# Lingo linear programming - Add restriction to table

Tags: lingo

i need to relacionar una restriccion que relacione 3 productos aceite de cartamo, oliva y coco y que este conectada con los 3 clientes los cuales son mayoristas, industriales y exclusivos para cada mes junio julio agosto en lingo

```
[This is a restriction for customer, demand, and product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxkB0.png)
```

```
SETS:
PRODUCTO/Aceitesesamo,AceiteCartamo,AceiteSoya/: PRECIO, COST_PRODUC; 
MES/Julio,Agosto,Septiembre/:CAP_PROD;
Insumos/VitaminaA,VitaminaD,Antioxidantes,Preservantes,SemillaSoya,SemillaSesamo,SemillaCartamo/:COST_INSUMO;
PXM (PRODUCTO, MES): DEMANDA,A, B;
MXI (MES, INSUMOS):E, D;
PXI (PRODUCTO, INSUMOS): REQ;
PXMXI (PRODUCTO, MES, INSUMOS) : ;
ENDSETS
DATA:

COST_PRODUC= 2.89 2.76 2.97;

COST_INSUMO= 1.5 1.3 2.2 1.5 3.5 3.5 3.8;

DEMANDA= 850    835 873
       837  748 859
       866  828 733;

PRECIO= 10.9 20.8 7.5;

CAP_PROD= 5000 5000 5000;

REQ=0.053   0.044   0.052   0.14    0     0.32  0
    0.053   0.044   0.052   0.14    0   0   0.34
    0.053   0.044   0.052   0.14    0.56    0   0;
ENDDATA
Max=@SUM(PXM (I, J): Precio(1) *DEMANDA (I, J)-COST_PRODUC (I) *A(I, J))-@SUM (PXMXI (I, J, K) :A(I, J) *REQ (I, K) *COST_INSUMO (K));
@FOR (PXM (I, J) | J#EQ#1:B(I, J) =A(I, J) -DEMANDA (I, J));
@FOR (PXM (I, J) | J#GE#2:B(I, J)=B(I, J-1)+A(I, J) -DEMANDA (I, J));
@FOR (MXI (J, K) | J#EQ#1:E(J,K) =D(J, K) -@SUM (PRODUCTO (I): REQ (I, K) *A (I, J)));
@FOR (MXI (J, K) | J#GE#2: E(J,K) =E (J-1, K) +D (J, K) -@SUM (PRODUCTO (I): REQ (I, K)*A(I, J))); 
@FOR(MXI(J,K)|J#GE#1:@SUM(PRODUCTO(I):REQ(I,K)*A(I,J))<=D(J,K));
@FOR(PxM(i,j):A(i,j)<=Cap_Prod(j));
```

How can I add the demand restriction for the three customers (Mayoristas, Industriales, and Exclusives) to this table?

Comment: sure @matt im so sorry for that :,) im new on stack overflow

Comment: sorry aa okok ya lo cambioo @matt :,)

Comment: sino que no se como cambiarlo ;-;

Comment: @matt ya lo cambie